# Approval Workflow with variable number of approvers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, visual-studio, workflow-manager

I am attempting to create an approval workflow with a variable number people who need to approve the item. For instance if employee A is pretty low on the org chart he or she may have 2-3 people approve the item. The workflow needs to query who the person's listed manager is and get an approval from him or her.  Then once that approval is gotten then it needs to go find who that manager's manager is and get the approval from them.  If the manager's managers field is blank the approval process stops or if the last manager is in a certain group it also stops.   Is this possible in Workflow Manager? How can this be done?

Comment: It sounds like you have it figured out. You should go ahead and try and build it and come back here if you have any problems. From what you've written, it sounds like it's possible. Just note that in a SharePoint 2013 workflow you'll need to use the HTTP Web Service activity with the correct end point URL to get the user's manager. In a SharePoint 2010 workflow (which you can also use in SharePoint 2013 by the way) there is a built in activity to get a user's manager.